# Grails 4 and eh-cache: @CachePut don't add keys to the named caches

Tags: hibernate, grails, ehcache

We have a grails 4 application (upgraded from grails 2.5.6). Now we realized that methods with the @CachePut annotation create named caches but didn't put the keys in. Which results in calling the @Cacheable method everytime. So the cache didn't work.

Here is the code and the dependencies:

```
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachePut
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable
...

class CacheService {

    @Cacheable(value='testCache', key='k1')
    def testCache(m){
        println "called testCache with m: $m"
        testCachePut(m)
    }

    @CachePut(value='testCache', key='k1')
    String testCachePut(m){
        println "called put"
        return "return Value for testCachePut, param m: $m"
    }
...
}
```

build.gradle:

```
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:7.0.7"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.18.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
```

application.groovy:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    allow_update_outside_transaction = true // else async mail plugin fails
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory'
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
    connection.charSet = 'utf8mb4'
    connection.characterEncoding='utf8mb4'
    connection.useUnicode=true
}
```

gradle.properties:

```
grailsVersion=4.0.13
gorm.version=7.0.8.RELEASE
```

logback.groovy:

```
    logger("org.hibernate.cache", DEBUG, ['STDOUT'])
```

We see only logs for the queries and finders, but even when a named cache is added, we didn't see a log. We didn't get logs for this namespaces:

- org.grails.plugins.cache
- org.hibernate.hibernate-ehcache

Only the name 'testCache' of the cache is in this log:

```
    println "cacheManager, all cache names: ${grailsCacheManager.getCacheNames()}"
    def cache = grailsCacheManager.getCache('testCache')
    println "cache size: ${cache.size()}"
```

The size of the cache 'testCache' remains 0.

We create an application from the scratch and only added the hibernate cache dependencies (also tried the initial versions) but we also there get the same result.

What can be wrong?